# get current cursor type in html(if the cursor is not set via css before, its default[auto]!)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is this even possible to get cursor type without predefined cursor style, just the default, the one that the web is rendered with?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the type of cursor that is being used at a certain point for an element with `cursor: auto`, e.g. an arrow by default, and an I-beam if the cursor is on text?

Comment: yes, I meant that.  When cursor is over link I want to get 'pointer', when it is over text I want to get 'text' and so on..can I manage that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **get** the css cursor property you can use:

```
var css_property = $('#selector').css('cursor');
```

To **set** a css cursor property you can use:

```
$('#selector').css({"cursor": "pointer"});
```

You'll need to use a [jQuery library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery).

Comment: so..if i have this there is no way to get alert that says pointer for example?

[link](http://pastebin.com/Rjizjjxk)

Comment: the cursor property is saved in the variable "css_property". If you add a click event or mouse over event for the area you can use alert(css_property). Here are examples: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: i guess you didn't saw the [link](http://pastebin.com/Rjizjjxk) I posted at the end of the example, it still says 'auto', I want to get it to say 'pointer' when I'm hovering a link, 'text' when I'm over text and so on..

Comment: Yeah but I want it to say 'pointer' because when you're going over the link the pointer from 'arrow' changes to 'hand(pointer)' right?
-Now what I'm asking is is there any way to popup the hand(pointer it is called I belive)?

Comment: Take this for example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FjJgK/2/).  When you are going over link the cursor from pointer changes to little hand which is called 'pointer', right? Further more..if you go over the paragraph the cursor changes to staight line(called 'text').  What is the point of this whole post is is there anyway to get them properly, so when i hover link i get 'pointer' and when i hover text/paragraph i get 'text'.  The following example the the once you posted above are all giving 'auto'..

Comment: Here, in the example you sent me you're using this line to check if it is pointer if(css_property =="pointer"), the problem is it always returns 'auto', that is the issue I'm struggling about..

Comment: but it always returns 'auto', how are you going to do it for the hover?
Because for the problem I have, the button can be ether pointer or arrow(default), how am I going to identify which one is current if it returns 'auto' for both cases?

Comment: I use Firefox and the default cursor setting for links there is pointer. If you want to return pointer you have to give your links the property cursor:pointer manually

Comment: hmm..My apologies, the solution you gave is working on firefox..I was trying it all the time on chrome, you have any idea how to do it here too?

Comment: look at the jsfiddle above. It add the css properties to all links

Comment: But if I don't have control over the button, can't I identify it on some different way, for example what if it is facebook like button which is spread all over the screen and If you havent pressed it, you're getting the hand cursor('pointer') style, if you have pressed it you are getting the arrow('default') style..

will adding the rule still work for facebook like button?

Comment: If you just want to detect links this is not the right thing to do it. Maybe with $('a').mouseover(function() { alert('this is a link'); });

Comment: Mhm, so...If I would go here [link](http://vklucise.mk/asd.html), what is the best way to detect indirectly if the user has liked the page or not?  -My idea was checking the cursor..Because the example you gave for detecting links doesn't seems to work..

Comment: sorry. I don't see any facebook links on that site. just a box in the middle in russian language

Comment: https://wordpress.org/ if you take that site and yours is simiarly you could check if the element with the text "like" is(':visible') or if the element with the text "unlike" is visible

Comment: The facebook like button is hidden in background btw, I didn't wanted to use facebook app to identify if user has liked the page or not (because it's not that nice), which would further more determine if the box with the 'russian langugae' would stay :).  -About this send post of yours, can you please be more specific because I didn't really understood you..

Comment: Please start a new question with sourcecode or screenshots or fiddles or something like that and please dont forget to accept (and like) my answer here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default cursor that a page is rendered with is "", which is typically an arrow.